# regular expression to match floating point number or decimal number

Tags: macros, latex3, xparse

To become somewhat familiar with the latex3 syntax, I've written a small macro to convert lengths (known in LaTeX).

I found the following on page 206 (229) in the last source3.pdf:

```
[+ - \ ] * ((? i) nan | inf | (\ d + | \ d * \. \ d +) (\ * e [+ - \ ] *
\ d +)?) \ *
```

But if I use that in the macro, I get an error message:

```
Range [+ -  ] out of order in character class.
```

It seems that the backslash with space is not interpreted correctly. But if I replace

```
[+ -\ ] with [+ -?]
```

then it seems to work.

What should be the correct input here?

I would be pleased about a hint.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator={\,},output-decimal-marker={,}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \convertlength } { O{} m m }
 {
   \tl_set:Nn \l_convert_length_tl { #2 }
   \regex_replace_all:nnN { [+-?]*((?i)nan|inf|(\d+|\d*\.\d+)(\ *e[+-?]*\d+)?)\ * } { \c{num}\cB\{ \0 \cE\}\c{,} } \l_convert_length_tl
   \ensuremath{ \text{ \tl_use:N \l_convert_length_tl }  =  \num[#1] { \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { #2 } { 1#3 } } \,\text{ #3 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\convertlength{1.5in}{cm} % cm mm nd pt dd bp in

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need an explicit space. So imho with active expl3 syntax `\~`.

Comment: `[+-?]` is the range from + to ? (cf `[a-z]`) I would guess `[+\-]` is what's wanted ( that is a plus or minus)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for that hint, thats right.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is right.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your explanation.

Comment: No I think I was wrong about the tilde, `\ ` works, but the order is wrong, the space is before the plus. You would get a similar error with [b-a]. With `[\ - +]` it works too (but is wrong too, as you want a minus as seen by the other comments).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer [\ - +] and [+\-] seems not to give the correct output., but with your first comment it does.

Comment: I didn't really check the regex. But `[+ - \~]` is the class "everything from + to  ~". This can't be correct in this context even if it gives by chance the correct output.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but when I look to source3.pdf on page 206 I find exact this [+-\ ]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the fix was mentioned in the comments (escaping the minus character) and the OP didn't clearly specify what this regex is referring to

Comment: The regular expression example was corrected in the sources some time ago.